# Sort List of ArrayLists by object field, only if exists

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a List which contains some `ArrayList`s of `Field` objects:

```
  ArrayList
(
    [0] => Field Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [name] => rank
            [value] => 2
        )

    [1] => Field Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [name] => user
            [value] => 234
        )

    [2] => Field Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [name] => location
            [value] => 10
        )

   ....
```

Some ArrayLists have a `Field` object with a name `rank` and a corresponding value, and some don't have that `rank` field at all.

I want to order those ArrayLists by the `rank` value (only if they contain it), and maintain the order of other ArrayLists that don't have the a `Field` object with `rank` in them.

It's also a possibility that 2 or more ArrayLists will have the same `rank` value, in which case i want them to maintain the order they had in relation to each other (meaning - if `AL5` and `AL6` have the same rank of `3`, they should appear before other `AL`s with lower ranks, but if `AL5` originally appeared before `AL6`, it should still be so. I hope that makes sense)

I'm only familiar with "basic Array sorting", this looks like a more tricky task..

Comment: Any chance you can convert this into `class Foo { @Nullable Integer rank; int user; int location; }`? It'd be a lot easier to work with...

Comment: You mean the code i posted? Sure, i'll edit it.

Comment: Do you have a single list, or a list of lists?

Comment: I mean transform your `List<ArrayList<Field>>` into `List<Foo>` so you can work with real objects and real fields.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd - `List` of `ArrayList`s.
@JohnKugelman yes that's definitely an option, thanks! I was just wondering if there's more "robust" solution that doesn't involve any transformations that maybe i hadn't heard of.

Comment: I recommend transforming, and can post an answer to that effect if you're open to it. I consider transformation the robust option (or maybe "elegant" is a better word). If you want to stick with the generic lists and `Field` objects that's also doable but the code'll be gnarlier.

Comment: @JohnKugelman sure, if you don't mind! Thanks!